# Tensorflow keras custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss

I have 1000 XRay images and I'm trying to make some binary predictions (died/lived). I have 900 'lived' pictures and 100 'died' pictures and after some reading (mostly [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-in-healthcare-x-ray-imaging-part-4-the-class-imbalance-problem-364eff4d47bb)), I think that I may have to make something about this imbalance of the samples.

I tried the

```
model.compile(...,loss=mycustom_loss,...)
```

approach but I think that I can't understand the syntax of the custom function. Reading some other documents, I tried the approach:

```
my_custom_loss_weights = [ 100/1000, 900/1000 ]  # index 0 is 'died', index 1 is 'lived'
model.compile = (...,loss='binary_crossentropy',loss_weights=my_custom_loss_weights,...)
```

which gave some pretty good results (loss and val_loss were very close, acc and val_acc were very close and high enough).

So the questions are about how to make a custom loss function returning binary_crossentropy but weighted based on my weights (100/1000 and 900/1000) and second, if the loss_weights parameter is the solution I want and I'm really that lucky!

I tried the oversample approach of the link I mentioned, but the results were terrible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's completely right how you are doing it, the `loss_weights` parameter is the way to go and also implemented correctly. It's also described in the link you posted under the paragraph `Weighted loss`.

Comment: Notlibus thank you. In the paragraph `Weighted loss` of the link  there is no mention of the parameter `loss_weights`, only the custom loss function.

Comment: If everything is correct, please remember to accept this as answer